# Remix not showing function buttons after the contract is successfully deployed

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.6.x

I am expecting Remix to show me buttons through which I could interact with the contract functions once I have deployed it successfully but the buttons are not showing you as can be seen in the below snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the contract selection box you have:

> Buffer - browser/test-run.sol

If you want to deploy SimpleOraclizeContract, it should be:

> SimpleOraclizeContract - browser/test-run.sol

Answer (score 0):

Selected the wrong contract in remix

select `SimpleOracilizeContract/test-run.sol`